# JList going blank [OutputStream Buffering issue i think]

Tags: java, swing, jlist, outputstream

I have this `JList` that I'm using as the display for `System.out`. I'm creating an IRC client with this `JList` at the bottom of the `JFrame`. It seems that whenever 2 or more elements are added to the `JLists` `ListModel` simultaneously, the whole `JList` becomes white and non-interactive until one single element is added by itself. An example of when multiple elements would be added simultaneously is when an exception prints the stack trace.

Here is the `OutputStream` class I have that is set as `System.out`...

```
public class LogOutputStream extends OutputStream {
    String sentence = "";
    boolean writing = false;
    private DefaultListModel subject;

    public LogOutputStream(DefaultListModel logListModel) {
        this.subject = logListModel;
    }

    public void write(final int b) {
        try {
            sentence = sentence + (char) b;

            if (sentence.endsWith("\n") && !sentence.isEmpty() && !sentence.equals("\t") && !sentence.equals("\r\n") && !sentence.equals("\n")) {
                if (writing == false) {
                    writing = true;
                    subject.addElement(sentence.replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "").trim());
                }

                sentence = "";
                writing = false;
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(Boot.stdErr);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here, and how it can be fixed?

Comment: Use [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) instead of blocking with writing.

Comment: I don't understand *anything.* Please clarify. How can output stream buffering do anything in a method that doesn't use the output stream? And how can a string end with a newline and be empty at the same time?

Comment: @EJP This class is substituting System.out by doing "System.setOut(new PrintStream(new LogOutputStream()));". The purpose is so I can have a custom console for logging. But when multi-line things such as exceptions print their stack trace it clogs it up or something causing the JList to stop showing any elements currently in it. Also, it checks if the string isn't empty then checks if it ends with a newline.

Comment: @norfavrell, I tried that and it doesn't make a difference. Thanks tho

Comment: @user1478724 The code you posted doesn't do any output. It therefore doesn't exhibit the problem you described. So either the problem isn't as you described or you didn't post enough code. The `isEmpty()` test in your code `if (sentence.endsWith("\n") && !sentence.isEmpty()` is redundant. If it ends with something it contains that something, and it therefore isn't empty. `isEmpty()` means contains zero characters. See the Javadoc. A String cannot contain a newline and be empty at the same time.

Comment: @EJP: the code actually does output indirectly via the `subject.addElement(...)` method call. This will try to write a String to the DefaultListModel. Other than his threading issues, his code does make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely a Swing concurrency issue in that you're adding items to the JList's model off of the event thread. This can tie up the thread and prevent it from doing its necessary actions of drawing the GUI or allowing for user interaction effectively freezing your Swing GUI.

Try making sure that you only write to the JList on the EDT (the Swing Event Dispatch Thread). Something like this will queue the `addElement(...)` call on the Swing event thread:

```
public void write(final int b) {
    try {
        sentence = sentence + (char) b;
        if (sentence.endsWith("\n") && !sentence.isEmpty()
                && !sentence.equals("\t") && !sentence.equals("\r\n")
                && !sentence.equals("\n")) {
            if (writing == false) {
                writing = true;
                final String text = sentence.replaceAll("\n", "")
                                .replaceAll("\r", "").trim();
                javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        subject.addElement(text);
                    }
                });

            }
            sentence = "";
            writing = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(Boot.stdErr);
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**
This is closer to something I've done in the past, using a StringBuilder:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JListOutputStream extends OutputStream {
   private DefaultListModel logListModel;
   private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   

   public JListOutputStream(DefaultListModel logListModel) {
      this.logListModel = logListModel;
   }

   @Override
   public void write(int b) throws IOException {
      if (b == '\r')
         return;

      if (b == '\n') {
         final String text = sb.toString().trim();
         sb.setLength(0);
         if (text.isEmpty()) {
            return;
         }
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               logListModel.addElement(text);
            }
         });

         return;
      }

      sb.append((char) b);
   }

}
```

**Edit 2**
As per this article titled [Writing Your Own Java I/O Stream Classes](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Streams/WritingIOSC/index.html), if you're extending OutputStream, don't forget to provide custom implementations for the `flush()` and `close()` methods.

Comment: This does work a bit better but sometimes it still hides when multiple elements are added.

Comment: Yeah I tried the second one (first one didn't work). Now that you mention it there is the while loop that keeps the client connected to the IRC server but that's in a separate thread so I didn't think that would matter.

Comment: Thanks mate you were a great help. Think I got it sorted mostly now.